# Select distinct rows and sum columns in DataTable VB.Net 2005

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2005

i have a dataTable contains:

ID  POCount POTotal 
  A           1                 10 
  A           2                 20 
  B           4                 10

I want to get a result of a new data table as bellow:
 ID  POCount POTotal 
  A           3                 30 
  B           4                 10

How can i do this using a datatable?
My project is in VB.NET 2005 and i cannot use LINQ method.
What is the best way to do this?

I found a link that kinda near what i want. But it just skip the rows instead of summing up the columns when the id is similar.
http://www.dotnetfunda.com/forums/show/2603/how-to-remove-duplicate-records-from-a-datatable

Answer (score 0):

LINQ is probably better - upgrade to later VS Express - its free!

Here is one approach using a class and a Dictionery

```
Public Class POSummary
    Public Property ID As String
    Public Property Count As Integer
    Public Property Total As Integer
    Sub New(POid As String, POcount As Integer, POtotal As Integer)
        ID = POid
        Count = POcount
        Total = POtotal
    End Sub
End Class
Private Sub Button12_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button12.Click
    Dim pos As New List(Of POSummary)
    Dim po As New POSummary("A", 1, 10)
    pos.Add(po)
    po = New POSummary("A", 2, 20)
    pos.Add(po)
    po = New POSummary("B", 4, 10)
    pos.Add(po)

    Debug.Print("--data--")
    For Each p As POSummary In pos
        Debug.Print(p.ID & " " & p.Count & " " & p.Total)
    Next

    Dim pd As New Dictionary(Of String, POSummary)

    For Each p As POSummary In pos
        If Not pd.ContainsKey(p.ID) Then
            pd.Add(p.ID, p)
        Else
            pd(p.ID).Count += p.Count
            pd(p.ID).Total += p.Total
        End If
    Next
    Debug.Print("--totals--")
    For Each kvp As KeyValuePair(Of String, POSummary) In pd
        po = kvp.Value
        Debug.Print(po.ID & " " & po.Count & " " & po.Total)
    Next
    Stop
End Sub
```

Comment: As much as i want, i cant upgrade my VS to latest one because this is a company project and i just maintaining the old source code. Do u have any other way to achieve this by just using datatable,dataview or datarow? I have the idea to do looping on my current data table and insert to the new datatable, and if col(id) is same, only sum count and row else, add new row added. But i dont know how to write it in such way.

Comment: You can loop on the rows in your datatable and use the Dictionary to roll-up the values. `for each row as datarow in mytable` Give it a try and post if you have problems. BTW I haven't experience any significant problems upgrading VS versions, we've done it several times with a big project. I highly recommend you catch up to the current version.